# Is it possible to use lambda expression in an Elasticsearch Path?

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, lambda, nest

I have an index containg amongst other a collection of objects, which in turn contains a bool that can only be true for one object in the collection. I want to be able to retrieve and sort only the element with this property set to true. I'm using ES v6.2.4

This works, but return the first item in the collection

```
var vesselSort = await _client.SearchAsync<SearchableSituation>(s => s
.Index(_situationIndexer.IndexName)
.From(message.Query.SearchResultsFrom)
.Size(message.Query.SearchResultsSize)
.Sort(sort => sort.Ascending(f => f.Status)
    .Field(x => x.Nested(y => y.Path(p => p.InvolvedVessels.First()))
        .Field(v => v.InvolvedVessels.First().VesselName.Suffix("keyword"))
        .Order(sortOrder)))
.Query(q => q
    .Bool(m => m
        .Must(queries))));
```

But I want to do something like this, which does not work:

```
var vesselSort2 = await _client.SearchAsync<SearchableSituation>(s => s
.Index(_situationIndexer.IndexName)
.From(message.Query.SearchResultsFrom)
.Size(message.Query.SearchResultsSize)
.Sort(sort => sort.Ascending(f => f.Status)
    .Field(x => x.Nested(y => y.Path(p => p.InvolvedVessels.First(v => v.IsRiskRole)))
        .Field(v => v.InvolvedVessels.First(iv=>iv.IsRiskRole).VesselName.Suffix("keyword"))
        .Order(sortOrder)))
.Query(q => q
    .Bool(m => m
        .Must(queries))));
```

queries is an optional filter to be applied but is default empty

```
public class SearchableSituation : IEquatable<SearchableSituation>
{
    public Guid SituationId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SearchableInvolvedVessel> InvolvedVessels { get; set;}
}

public class SearchableInvolvedVessel : IEquatable<SearchableInvolvedVessel
{
    public string VesselName { get; set; }

    public bool IsRiskRole { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you share your types (`SearchableSituation` etc)?

Comment: Added some code.
Also see my previous question for more details:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59561611/why-does-my-sorted-nested-elasticsearch-with-custom-analyzer-using-nest-return-i

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass your condition as in a new query inside the .Nested

```
.Nested(
      y => y
      .Path(p => p.InvolvedVessels)
      .Query(qq => qq
             .Bool(*your bool query*)
  ))
```

Comment: I don't have .Query as a possible option in the .Nested expression

Comment: Well i got it using a 5.5.X es (nest 5.3.0).
You sure about that? reflection mess up sometime in visual.

Comment: Yes, quite sure. Have tried to paste your code directly and write manually, but will not build. Will try to find any changes in the interface from 5.x to 6.x

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing, and seems to be working was to add a Filter condition:

```
.Nested(n => n.Path(p => p.InvolvedVessels).Filter(f => f.Term("involvedVessels.isRiskRole", true)))
                    .Field(v => v.InvolvedVessels.First().VesselName.Suffix("keyword"));
```